# Transaction Replication Issue

Tags: sql-server, replication, snapshot

I am trying to set up a Transaction Replication. I encountered error when i created a Publisher.While creating publisher i gave SQL Server agent accounts for Snapshot Agent and Log Reader Agent. When I checked the Log reader agent it is running, but Snapshot agent is giving error message as below:

> Access to the path 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\ReplData\unc\EAICS-SQL-01_TEST_REPL_1_TEST_PUB2\20180502143109\' is denied.

I went to that path and there is no `\unc\` folder created.
Do you have any suggestions?

**Additional details**

I gave service account for SQL Server Agent and DB engine as `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICES`. So I believe it is not a domain service account. `SQL-1` and `SQL-2` are my server names. I created Publisher at `SQL-1`, so SQL-1 server account will already have access to the folder right?

Comment: Give the service account access to `D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\ReplData`. it will then create the rest.

Comment: Can you use domain account and try what I asked above ?